# How do I change the target Android version in AndroidStudio for a PhoneGap/Cordova app?

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

When I try to run the default PhoneGap HelloWorld app, I get `ERROR: Error: Please install Android target: "android-22".` in the run. This is expected since I have the 23 SDK installed on this machine.

My issue is, though, that my AndroidManifest.xml file has the line:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />
```

I tried to use Find In Path to find any instances of 22 in my project directory, and it couldn't find anything other than 5 instances within CSS files (so nothing denoting a dependency on android-22). I have no clue where it's getting that it needs 22 instead of 23.

23 is what is declared as the SDK in the Project Structure. 
If applicable, I'm on a Mac (El Capitan). I just started this last night, so it was just a fresh project made from the PhoneGap desktop app, then opened in AndroidStudio. Cordova is installed and detected fine as is the PhoneGap/Cordova plugin for AndroidStudio. I've been wanting to just get this building before actually starting development.

Within the AndroidManifest file: I notice every time I click Run, if I changed `android:versionCode` to 1 instead of 10000 or change `android:minSdkVersion` to 8 instead of 14 (edit: That's my bad, I had 14 in the config.xml. 1 is in the config file, too, though, so I don't know what's up with that), it reverts those changes. It didn't care that I changed 22 to 23 when I first opened the project, though. That setting stays across Run attempts it just isn't honored.

The only issue I know of by using El Capitan is that the hardware accelerated emulator is picky about me being on 10.11 instead of 10.10, but it would be whining about that if that was the issue rather than whining about my SDK version. I'd really rather not install 22 if I don't have to since these SDKs suck up so many gigs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the same directory where there is  AndroidManifest,
there will be a file project.properties
open and edit that file and change 22 to 23 the following line.
Save it and exit.
Build the android platform again.

target=android-22

Please let me know if that helps.
Thanks